# Xamarin PCL Refit 3.0.1 , Doesn't look like a Refit interface

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, nuget-package, reactiveui, refit

I recently started working on a Xamarin Android/iOS project with a PCL class where I want to put all the logic in. Like my Refit interfaces, ReactiveUI ViewModels et cetera, but every time when trying to execute my code I get a error saying that my interface is not a Refit interface. Currently my interface looks like this.

```
public interface IMyApi
{
    [Post("/authenticate")]
    IObservable<Models.ApiResponses.AuthenticationResponse> SigninRaw([Body] JObject credentials);

    [Get("/service")]
    IObservable<Models.ApiResponses.MyListResponse> GetServiceListRaw();

    [Get("/service/{id}/idstatus")]
    IObservable<Models.ApiResponses.IdResponse> GetIdStatusRaw(string Id);
}
```

As far as I know this looks good and this also works when I'm trying to load this from a specific platform like iOS project. But when trying to do it from a PCL if fails! I have installed the Refit package in both of my platform specific project Android & iOS and I referenced a dll in the PCL, what did I miss?

If there is need for more information or you have any question, please do not hesitate to ask.
Well without further ado, thank you for reading and hopefully someone can assist me with this, because I starting to loose my mind the past couple of days.

Edit: added calling method.
Here I calling it from a ViewModel

```
var client = new HttpClient(NetCache.UserInitiated)
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.address.com")
};

var api = RestService.For<IMyApi>(client); <= here it crashes
var response = api.SigninRaw(token);
```

Comment: How did you get the Post/Get attributes to compile in your interface? Whenever I try to add the refit project to a PCL project I get an error message saying the project type isn't supported, which IMO kinda defeats the whole point of using it in a PCL project. You haven't inadvertently used attributes from a different namespace, have you?

Comment: @MarkFeldman I know what you mean, I have had the same problem. I have read someones post that you should download the nuget packages in your platform specific projects and then you should reference the dll into your PCL project and than as far as I know it should work. But when I do that I get this message. "Refit doesn't look like a refit interface". Hopefully this can help you. Please ask if you have questions.

Comment: I finally got around to trying this myself, having exactly the same problem. Good thing it's open-source...I'm going to clone the repo locally and track down the problem. I can't think of any reason why this shouldn't be working.

Comment: answer added below.

Answer (score 4):

I've managed to track this down, there are actually a few issues at play. Fortunately there are ways to work around them.

The first problem is that the PCL interfaces aren't being detected in the first place. Refit runs a utility at compile time (InterfaceStubGenerator) which scans the subfolders for interface classes and generates implementation code for each one. These are all packed into an intermediate file called RestStubs.g.cs which gets included in with the assembly. This utility, however, is only run on the projects that Refit has been added to via nuget, and since that doesn't include PCL projects the interfaces in those projects never get processed. The solution is to call this utility manually in a pre-build step and include the generated file in each of the platform projects. Go to your PCL project's property settings and add the following to the pre-build steps:

```
..\..\..\..\packages\refit.3.0.1\tools\InterfaceStubGenerator.exe ..\..\..\ProjName.Droid\RefitStubs.cs ..\..\..\ProjName
..\..\..\..\packages\refit.3.0.1\tools\InterfaceStubGenerator.exe ..\..\..\ProjName.iOS\RefitStubs.cs ..\..\..\ProjName
```

That will generate RefitStubs.cs for your platform projects, so add each file to it's respective project.

Ordinarily that would be the end of it were it not for another problem. The RestService.For<> generics that you call to get the implementations make the assumption that the implementation classes reside in the same assembly as their corresponding interfaces. Obviously that isn't the case for PCL projects. To get around this you need to implement your own version of the RestService class, this will probably serve most of your needs:

```
public static class PclRestService
{
    public static T For<T>(string hostUrl)
    {
        var className = "AutoGenerated" + typeof(T).Name;
        var typeName = typeof(T).Namespace + "." + typeof(T).Name.Replace(typeof(T).Name, className);
        var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var generatedType = assembly.GetType(typeName);
        var requestBuilder = RequestBuilder.ForType<T>();           
        var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()) { BaseAddress = new Uri(hostUrl) };
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(generatedType, client, requestBuilder);
    }
}
```

You then call it like so:

```
var netService = PclRestService.For<IMyApi>("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com");
var result = await netService.GetDataOrSomething();
```

One last problem you may encounter is multiple declarations of the PreserveAttribute class, which is declared at the top of the stub files. So long as you don't add Refit interfaces to your platform projects this shouldn't happen, but if it does then you have 3 options:

1. modify the InterfaceStubGenerator utility to not create that code
2. write a pre-processor to strip that code out once it has been generated
3. go to Refit's "refit.targets" file and comment-out the line `"<Exec Command="$(RefitExecCmd)" />`

The Refit tools folder includes the template file used to generate stub files but for some strange reason it's ignored altogether and statically linked to the application, so editing it in the tools folder doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: Great answer thanks! Crazy complicated to get this working though. Ai why doesn't they have PCL support.

Comment: Interestingly enough I went to a Xamarin Hackday back in December and was speaking to a few guys who say they don't have this problem. Only difference between their environment and mine is I was on Visual Studio for Windows and they were on Xamarin Studio for Mac. Go figure.

Comment: Weird ai.. very frustrating - massive problem hey . Buying myself a mac ;)